# How to get PHP session variable deeply nested inside array?

Tags: php

Have tried a number of permutations to get a value from a PHP session.  The session is an array of objects I think with key value pairs.  This is the structure as outputted by a key/value foreach loop

```
Array
(
    [laboratory_roster] => Array
        (
            [employee_entrance] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [step] => employee_entrance
                    [employee_first_name] => asdfasd
                    [employee_last_name] => fasdfasdfv
                    [employee_access_code] => valid
                    [employee_email] => blah@blah.com
                    [employee_state_origin] => NY
                    [employee_kit_for_whom] => employee_kit_for_employee
                )

        )

)
```

This is the foreach loop that I wrote to display the output above:

```
   foreach($_SESSION['laboratory_roster']['employee_entrance'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
```

What I wish to do is simply assign the value of the innermost value to a variable.  Nothing works.  Have tried:

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['employee_entrance']['employee_first_name'];
```

and this...

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['employee_entrance'][1];
```

and this...

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['laboratory_roster']['employee_entrance']['employee_first_name'];
```

and this...

```
 $first_name = $_SESSION['laboratory_roster']['employee_entrance']['employee_first_name'][0];
```

Nothing works!  It's probably so simple how to get the innermost value into a PHP variable, but I am not getting it.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$first_name = $_SESSION['laboratory_roster']['employee_entrance']->employee_first_name;
```

As employee_entrance is an object (instance of `stdClass`) and not an array.

Comment: tried this as well:    $first_name = $_SESSION['laboratory_roster']['employee_entrance']->employee_first_name;

Comment: @Rachel it has to work, according to the example posted. See https://3v4l.org/00XMi

Comment: @Oliver it doesn't though.  if I do this.. I get nothing rendered:
    $first_name = $_SESSION['[laboratory_roster']
    ['employee_entrance']->employee_first_name;

        echo('First Name' . $first_name);

Comment: Something must have been cached/wonky.  Working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:
1 Convert to stdClass: `$stdClass = json_decode(json_encode($_SESSION));` Then access with `[]`.
2 Convert to array: `$array = json_decode(json_encode($_SESSION), true);` Then access with `->`.

Comment: The other way around.